# SQL Server deadlock LINQ to SQL

Tags: sql-server, linq, deadlock

I'm trying to find a definitive answer for this. If you select and then update, using Linq on SQL Server, in a serializable transaction, is there a deadlock risk? eg:

```
using (var trans = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable, Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) }))
{
    using (var con = new MyContext())
    {
        var record = con.MyTable.Single(t => t.id == 1);    // share lock?

        record.field = 99;
        con.SubmitChanges();                                // upgraded to exclusive lock? possible deadlock

        trans.Complete();
    }
}
```

And since this is such a common pattern, is the only way to avoid it something like:

```
var record = con.ExecuteQuery<MyTable>("select * from MyTable with (updlock) where id = {0}", 1).Single();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a classic deadlock. Two transactions both read, then both attempt to update. Both must wait for the other to release the shared lock.

With an optimistic concurrency model this would result in a write conflict.

The `UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK` hint combo is what I usually use in these cases. Note, that for convenience reasons you can execute this locking query using `ExecuteQuery`, discard the results and then use LINQ normally. You don't need to switch everything into SQL.

L2S and EF do not allow you to set table hints. This is unfortunate. You have to resort to SQL on some level. Either manually or using a function or a wrapper view.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is UPDLOCK alone not enough?

Comment: Also, has anyone written an extension method to modify the expression tree to do this nicely? eg allowing `con.MyTable.WithUpdateLock().Single(...);`

Comment: L2S and EF do not allow you to set table hints. There's no way to apply this information to an expression tree. UPDLOCK is enough because you are running under SERIALIZABLE which is equivalent to HOLDLOCK. I still force HOLDLOCK so that the query is more stable with respect to its surrounding isolation level